# Ruby Regex to round trailing zeros

Tags: ruby, regex, fractions, decimal-point

I'm looking for a regex to remove trailing zeros from decimal numbers. It should return the following results:

```
0.0002300 -> 0.00023
10.002300 -> 10.0023
100.0     -> 100
1000      -> 1000
0.0       -> 0
0         -> 0
```

Basically, it should remove trailing zeros and trailing decimal point if the fraction part is 0. It should also return 0 when that's the value. Any thoughts? thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the regex:

```
(?:(\..*[^0])0+|\.0+)$
```

and replace it with:

```
\1
```

A demo:

```
tests = ['0.0002300', '10.002300', '100.0', '1000', '0.0', '0']
tests.each { |tst|
  print tst, " -> ", tst.sub(/(?:(\..*[^0])0+|\.0+)$/, '\1'), "\n"
}
```

which produces:

```
0.0002300 -> 0.00023
10.002300 -> 10.0023
100.0 -> 100
1000 -> 1000
0.0 -> 0
0 -> 0
```

Or you could simply do `"%g" % tst` to drop the trailing zeros:

```
tests = ['0.0002300', '10.002300', '100.0', '1000', '0.0', '0']
tests.each { |tst|
  s = "%g" % tst
  print tst, " -> ", s, "\n"
}
```

which produces the same output.

Comment: I think it's a lot more complicated than it needs to be but it works so +1.

Comment: :), I fully agree @Mark. I glared at it a little, but can't see a short-cut though...

Answer (score 12):

just another way

```
["100.0","0.00223000"].map{|x|"%g"%x}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great! Your solution "%g"%x is only 6 characters!

Answer (score 1):

Here is bit more optimized regex solution.

Search for this regex:

```bash
(?:(\.[0-9]*[1-9])|\.)0+$
```

and replace with:

```
\1
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/utbsZC/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `(\.[0-9]*[1-9])`: Match a dot followed by 0+ instances of any digit and then a digit `1-9`. Capture this value in group #1 (to be used in replacement back-reference `\1`)
  - `|`: OR
  - `\.`: Match a dot
- `)`: End non-capture group
- `0+`: Match 1+ of zeroes
- `$`: End